# jbutton does not work

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

Hi I have the following code where I have a start and stop button . when start is pressed canvas starts painting but I cannot press stop button until the start operation is done . I need to stop and resume the paint on the button press . Once the start button is pressed the other buttons cannot be pressed till the canvas is painted.

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public abstract class JUIApp extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    public static CACanvas cacanvas= null;
    public ArrayList<int[]> genL;
    public JFrame frame = null;
    protected JPanel mainPanel = null;
    private JButton btn0 = null;
    private JButton btn1 = null;
    private JButton btn2 = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    DefaultComboBoxModel rules = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    JComboBox rulesCombo =null;
    JScrollPane ruleListScrollPane=null;
    JLabel lable=null;
    JTextField generation=null;
    JLabel gLable=null;
    public static String Rule;
    public  static String Generations;
    public boolean isChanged =false;
    public int gridCellSize=4;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int genCurrent=0;
    public int posCurrent=0;
    public int i;
    public Color cellColor= null;
    public Timer waitTimer;
    public static boolean waitFlag;
    public static boolean alert1Flag=false;
    public boolean stopFlag=false;
    public JLabel Alert1=new JLabel();
    public int genCheck=0;
    //private List<Point> fillCells;
    public JUIApp() {
        initGUI();

    }
    public void initGUI() {
        //fillCells = new ArrayList<>(25);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Cellular Automata Demo");
        frame.setSize(1050, 610);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(getMainPanel(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout(false); 
         cacanvas=new CACanvas();
            frame.add(cacanvas);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public JPanel getMainPanel() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //cacanvas=new CACanvas();

        btn0 = new JButton("Start");
        btn0.addActionListener(this);
        //waitTimer = new Timer(1000, this);
        mainPanel.add(btn0);

        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Stop");
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent s)
            {
                stopFlag=true;
                //cacanvas.repaint();
            }
        });
        mainPanel.add(btn2);
        btn1 = new JButton("Clear");
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                CACanvas.clearFlag=true;
                generation.setText("");
                alert1Flag=true;
                rulesCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);
                  Alert1.setText("Please enter the number of generations");
                  Alert1.setBounds(30, 20, 5, 5);
                  Alert1.setVisible(alert1Flag);
                  mainPanel.add(Alert1);
                   cacanvas.repaint();
                   frame.setSize(1060, 610);

            }
    });
        mainPanel.add(btn1);
        lable=new JLabel();
        lable.setText("Select Rule :");
        mainPanel.add(lable);
        rules=new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        for (int i=0;i<=100;i++)
        {
            String p=String.valueOf(i);
        rules.addElement(p);
        }
        rules.addElement("250");
        rules.addElement("254");
        rulesCombo = new JComboBox(rules);    
        rulesCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);

         ruleListScrollPane = new JScrollPane(rulesCombo);
        mainPanel.add(ruleListScrollPane);
        //mainPanel.revalidate();
        gLable=new JLabel();
        gLable.setText("Enter the number of Generations (Max 64)");
        generation=new JTextField(2);

        mainPanel.add(gLable);
        mainPanel.add(generation);
       // mainPanel.add(cacanvas);
        return mainPanel;
    }


    public abstract void run();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Alert1.setVisible(false);
        waitFlag=false;
        System.out.println("We received an ActionEvent " + arg0);
         Generations=generation.getText();
        System.out.println(Generations);

         Rule = "";
        if (rulesCombo.getSelectedIndex() != -1) {                     
           Rule = 
                   (String) rulesCombo.getItemAt
                (rulesCombo.getSelectedIndex());             
        } 
        System.out.println(Rule);
        int rule=Integer.parseInt(Rule);
     Hashtable<String,Integer> rules= new Hashtable<String,Integer>();
        CARule ruleClass=new CARule();
        rules=ruleClass.setRule(rule);
        CAGenetationSet sa =new CAGenetationSet(100, false,rules);
         genL=new ArrayList<int[]>();
         genL=sa.runSteps(Integer.parseInt(Generations));
         System.out.println("calling pattern set");
        for(int i=0;i<=genL.size()-1;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Painting generation :"+i);

            if(stopFlag==false)
            {

               cacanvas.repaint();
            }

            //genPaint();
            //sleep();
            int[] newCell=genL.get(i);
            for(int r=0;r<newCell.length;r++)
            {

                if(newCell[r]==1)
                {


                    System.out.println("Generaton is"+i+"CellLife is"+r);
                    cacanvas.fillCell(i,r);


        }
            }

        }




                    /*cacanvas.patternSet(genL);
                    waitFlag=true;


                  System.out.println("run completed");
                 // cacanvas.clearFlag=true;
*/  
    }   

    public void genPaint()
    {
        cacanvas.repaint();
    }

    public void sleep()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JUIApp app = new JUIApp() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Run method");

            }



    };
}
}
```

Comment: The likely reason is, you're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, which is responsible for, among other things, handling paint event. You could use a Swing `Timer` or `SwingWorker` to resolve the issue.  See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I went through the Concurrency notes but an example would be much easier to explain the concept . I am a beginner so do you mind editing the above code with a few lines of the concurrency concept.

Comment: Since you code is incomplete and not compilable or runnable, it's hard to make suggestions about how best to implement either of the solutions'

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using the current Thread on that task, you should create another Thread and add one listeners code to the new Thread.